# Given an array of Long values in Kotlin and a position parameter, when the position is in the middle of two of the array values, return the lowest

Tags: android, arrays, list, kotlin, android-jetpack

Spotify's lyrics API provides an Array of miliseconds to mark when the lyric line has changed. Having a Media Player that updates it's position every 50ms, how should i code in Kotlin the way to find the correct lyric line? The position param can be in the middle of two values of the array, so I want to get the lowest one of that two.

I tried to get the lowest value compared to the position parameter but lol, it will always be the first value of the Array... Silly fault of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I have a third one that indicates the range of that two value. For example: I have an Array of [45, 78, 125, 198]. If I pass the position param where it's value is 95, I want to return the 78 (that is the lowest value from itself, the position param and 125).

```
/** Input data for example (from your comment). */
val yourArray = arrayOf(45, 78, 125, 198)
val inputValue = 95

/** How to get needed index. */
val resultIndex = yourArray.indexOfLast { it < inputValue }.takeIf { it != -1 }
```

If you get `resultIndex == null` - it means you don't have value inside your array which lower then your `inputValue`.

I think it's simpler than find `indexOfFirst` and compare result later. And absolutely better and safer when `sort()` solution.

Comment: Oh, haha, I didn’t even remember there was an indexOfLast. That is definitely simpler.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this code in a few hours and i tell you!

Answer (score 1):

Insert the position param into the array, sort it, find its index and use it to get the closest value.

```kotlin
    val array: MutableList<Long> = mutableListOf(4L, 9L, 5L, 1L)
    val position = 7L
    
    array.add(position)
    println(array[array.sorted().indexOf(position) - 1])
```

Output: 5

Comment: You may get `NullPointerException` if your position will be first item inside your `list`. Because you use unsafe operation `get()` and index may be in some cases equals `-1`. Use `getOrNull()`   at least.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you need simply use `min` function for compare two numbers in `Kotlin` and find the low one: [link](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/min.html)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for you answer. The problem is that I have a third one that indicates the range of that two value. For example: I have an Array of [45, 78, 125, 198]. If I pass the position param where it's value is 95, i want to return the 78 (that is the lowest value from itself, the position param and 125).

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a way to do it without having to make two copies of the list and doing a sort.

```
val foundIndex = lyricTimesList.indexOfFirst { it > inputTime }
val result = if (foundIndex == -1) lyricTimesList.size - 1 else foundIndex - 1
```

Note the result could be -1 if the input time is less than the first number in the list.

Comment: Oh nice! That's really good. I was thinking about that amount of memory used in the other snippet of code has to be huge